# Python poetry stops with exit code 1 but no error message in CICD

Tags: python, git, pip, python-poetry

I am running `poetry install -vvv --no-interaction` in the CICD environment as part of CI.
We recently updated poetry to 1.6.1. This is the latest version as of today. The build was passing. But then this started to happen.

```
  #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
poetry install --no-interaction -vvv

Loading configuration file /root/.config/pypoetry/config.toml
Loading configuration file /root/project1/poetry.toml
Using virtualenv: /code/.venv
Installing dependencies from lock file

Finding the necessary packages for the current system
[keyring.backend] Loading KWallet
[keyring.backend] Loading SecretService
[keyring.backend] Loading Windows
[keyring.backend] Loading chainer
[keyring.backend] Loading libsecret
[keyring.backend] Loading macOS
No suitable keyring backend found
No suitable keyring backends were found
Keyring is not available, credentials will be stored and retrieved from configuration files as plaintext.
[urllib3.connectionpool] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): bitbucket.org:443
[urllib3.connectionpool] https://bitbucket.org:443 "GET /org1/django-yubin.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 None
Cloning https://bitbucket.org/org1/django-yubin.git at 'HEAD' to /code/.venv/src/django-yubin

Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals, 232 skipped

Error:
Exited with code exit status 1
```

Here the warning `Keyring is not available, credentials will be stored and retrieved from configuration files as plaintext` is in color yellow.

What is the problem here? How to fix it?

Comment: it's related to this bug https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/7184

Answer (score 0):

Could be a lot of things.

First, check that you have keyring installed

```bash
$ keyring
```

If that fails do:

```bash
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-keyring
```

Now check that you have the appropriate backend installed. For linux it should be SecretStorage

```bash
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-secretstorage
```

Next, check that `keyring` is configured to use secretstorage

```bash
$ keyring --list-backends
keyring.backends.SecretService.Keyring (priority: 5)
keyring.backends.fail.Keyring (priority: 0)
keyring.backends.chainer.ChainerBackend (priority: -1)
```

Next, check that your credentials are stored in the keyring

```bash
$ keyring get poetry-repository-<repo_name_in_pyproject> <username>
```

Where `<repo_name_in_pyproject>` is whatever you named the source under `[[tool.poetry.source]]` and `<username>` is the username you've configured poetry to use

If nothing shows up then you haven't configured the key in the keyring. The easiest way is to do:

```bash
$ poetry config http-basic.<repo_name_in_pyproject> <username> <password>
```

You can also omit `<password>` and you will be prompted to enter it in a secure manner in terminal

This command will accomplish two things

1. Add the username/password to the keyring
2. Add the authentication settings to `~/.config/pypoetry/auth.toml`. Note that the password field will not appear in `auth.toml` since it is insecure to store store credentials in plaintext and poetry will use `keyring` to retrieve the password anyway

If, after all these steps you still can't authenticate you have basically two options I know of:

1. set up the `POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_<REPO_NAME_IN_PYPROJECT>_USERNAME` and `POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_<REPO_NAME_IN_PYPROJECT>_PASSWORD` environment variables and try again
2. set the environment variable `PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring` and instead store your password in poetrys `auth.toml` under your username (`password = "<password>"`)

If you're still having issues then I have no idea how to help you XD

See also:

1. https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#configuring-credentials
2. https://github.com/jaraco/keyring